# Runtime error using array[100] in C

Tags: c, arrays, char, initialization, switch-statement

I'm kind of a beginner in C. I was was trying to run this code in Code::Blocks and Ideone and both gave me the same runtime error. I tried changing `arr[100]` to `arr[101]` and astonishingly enough, the code ran. I am also worried about the initialisation of `poo[t]`, because it doesn't seem to store the value of `sum` in it. Or maybe the `sum` retains the value `0` (Could it be that the `switch` statement does not allow `char` cases?)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int arr[100], t, poo[t], i, j, sum; // refer HOLES

   scanf("%d", &t);

   for (i=0; i<t; i++) {
        scanf("%s", arr);
        j=0;
        sum = 0;
        while (arr[j] != '\0') {
            switch (arr[j])
            {
            case 'B':
                sum = sum + 2;
                break;
            case 'A':
            case 'D':
            case 'O':
            case 'P':
            case 'Q':
            case 'R':
                sum++;
                break;
            default:
                break;
            }
            j++;
        }
        poo[i] = sum;
        printf("%d", poo[i]);
   }

   for (i=0; i<t; i++)
   {
        printf("%d \n", poo[i]);
   }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input are you feeding the program when it crashes?

Comment: I think the issue lies with the initialization of poo[t]. t is non-const, and array declarations require a const value.

Comment: Are you feeding it text which is 100 characters long (or longer)? It will break in that case. You should use safer input code anyway.

Comment: honestly i don't get this poo[t], static allocation should be static.

Comment: and a 100 characters long text fits in 101 array (because you have to add the \0 terminator of the string).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int arr[100];
scanf("%s", arr);
```

if `arr` was meant to be a string, it should be declared as `char` array:

```
char arr[100];
scanf("%s", arr);
```

---

*" I am also worried about the initialisation of `poo[t]`"*

You should be. The following declaration:

```
int t, poo[t];
scanf("%d", &t);
```

uses unitialized variable `t` invoking an ***undefined behavior***.

Declare `poo` after the `t` is properly initialized:

```
int t = 0;
scanf("%d", &t);
int poo[t];
```

Answer (score 1):

this line

```
int arr[100], t, poo[t], i, j, sum; // refer HOLES
```

is not good since `t` is not initialized before use.

If you really want to use `VLA`, do like this

```
int t;
scanf("&d", t);

int poo[t];
```

Comment: Recommended fix: if you have an upper limit for t, i.e. `t <= N`, then have `int poo[N];`.

Answer (score 0):

One of the problems here is this line:

```
scanf("%s", arr);
```

Note that `arr` is declared as

```
int arr[100];
```

This means that you are reading a string (a series of `char`s) into an array of integers.  This doesn't cause each integer to hold one character; instead, the bytes of the integers will be filled in using character values.  Consequently, when you iterate over the elements of the array, you will not get back clean values like `\0`.

To fix this, change the declaration of `arr` so that it's a `char` array:

```
char arr[100];
```

There may be other issues here, but this is certainly an issue you'll need to fix.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You should put  `poo[t]` after `scant` which reads actual size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`poo[t]` is a variable length array, valid in C99. To use VLA you must assign a value to `t`.